# JQuery media modal section loads only sometimes

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, media

I have a media section which used to load fine but recently it started to give 500 error intermittently and it works if kept re-trying.

This is what it shows in the console:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjOu7.png

There hasn't been any changes to code either.

Any idea on what it may have caused to behave like this now?

Comment: Error 500 is server side error. Check the logs for more details and update your question with the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a similar issue, where the database grew so large, that the call ran our of memory. You can increase it by changing the `memory_limit` in your `php.ini`.

Besides it is quite helpful to call the URI returning the 500 (internal Server Error) directly if you want to go deeper into debugging the issue. You might need to change the route from `post` to `get` though...